# In React/Redux app, when should I pass down a prop explicitly versus picking it up from global state using mapStateToProps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building my first React-Redux app and in many cases I have a choice of either doing `<PaginationBox perPage={perPage} />` or having `<PaginationBox />` and then do

```
function mapStateToProps({pagination: {page}}) {
  return {
    pageNumber: page + 1
  };
}
```

What are the implications of using one way or another and when should I prefer one over the other?

Are there any established best practices on how to pick up props? I feel a little bad every time I use `mapStateToProps` in some deeply nested component because it feels like the component gets coupled to the state of the particular page/app.

Comment: Can you post an example of your components tree ?

Comment: Ideally child components should be dumb. They should not alter or have any influence on a state. I believe mapStateToProps would be fine to use at a parent component level but props should be passed down to child components

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question. If it's possible to decouple the component from the state then do so. It's all answered here https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.c7k4dfcec

Answer (score 4):

There is no single good answer.  Per the Redux FAQ at http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#react-multiple-components , it's up to you to decide where in your component hierarchy it makes sense to connect a component.  It could be at the "LeftSidebar / RightMainPanel" level, or it could be much more granular.  In some cases, such as trying to optimize a list for performance, you might have the List itself be connected and retrieve the item IDs, and every ListItem would themselves be connected and retrieve their own data by ID.

For this particular case, I'd probably lean towards having a `<PaginationBox />` be connected, and render stateless functional `<PaginationItem />` components as necessary, mostly just because the individual items aren't going to need any real information attached other than a number and a link to click.  But, that's just an opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Did you already have a look into the presenter/container components pattern? There exist multiple [good article](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.4kv7pdkx4)s around this pattern, which give you most of the time a good idea of when to have a presenter or container component

**My advice:**

Start with one container component (which has mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps) at the top of your component hierarchy. Below stick to presenter components which only receive props and actions. There will be a time when you notice that **(A)** one presenter component needs a lot of properties/actions itself or that **(B)** you are passing properties/actions for too many levels down and only some of them are grabbed by components in between.

Then you start to exchange presenter with container components for *fat* components **(A)**. When there are still too many actions/properties passed **(B)**, you need to think about more container components, which take care of avoiding too deep props/actions passing.

But your first rule could be: one container component on top, all components below are presenters.

Comment: I use the same solution for my project and I get some problem with it. Most common is a lot of rewritable code. A lot of my git commits it's just exchanging presenter components with containers (and vice versa). So I can not imagine basic application structure at the start of development.
Also I have one question about naming and folder structure. How do you name your containers (for example name of presenter is ListItem, and what about container name)? And the same with folder names: do you keep folder structure in containers folder the same as in presenters folder?

Comment: You are right: A lot of time in React development you will invest in refactoring. It is the same for me and the people in my company. 

About the naming and folder structure: When I have a component ListItem, I usually tend to have a folder named ListItem with multiple files. 1x presenter.js, 1x container.js, 1x index.js (entry point to the folder to expose at leat the container component), 1x spec.js, 1x style.less/css/..., ... You could even add more files like: contants.js, service.js for more functionality. The folder gets a module itself with its own functionality, style etc.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to pass values/methods to child components, we use props. Props are used to check whether the required value or method is available to the current component from some other component. Let's assume i have two methods one is selection-header and another buyItems. From selection header i select all the items from the list shown and send that to buyItems component to do purchase. Here buyItems component require value from selection-header and that is compulsory. This type of checking done throw props.

Instead of using props we can also use mixins. Mixins allow us to use another component method in present component.

```
    var selection-header = React.createClass({
      selectItems: function(){
        itemsSelectAll: true
      },
      render: function(){
        return(
         <BuyItems />
       );
      }
   });

var BuyItems = React.createClass({
      mixins: [selection-header],  
    render: function(){
        return(
       );
      }
   });
```

now in buyitems component we can use selection header methods and variables

Comment: Mixins appear to have a limited future in React.  They are not compatible with ES6 classes, for example.  See links below for more info:

https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.4odvvoqig

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/13/mixins-considered-harmful.html

Answer (score 0):

This topic is a somewhat subjective and there are no hard and fast rules. So I'll just tell you what I do.

Typically, I try to only connect to the store in the container (parent component, smart component, etc...). Then I pass props from the container to the component ( dumb component ) which is not connected to the store.

I always strive for a hierarchy of Store --> Container --> Props --> Component.

That being said, it doesn't always make sense to stick to that hierarchy at all times it is simply that I always try to do first.

I definitely understand what you are saying that connecting a component to the store that is buried in your component hierarchy can feel a bit dirty not to mention hard to maintain.

Here's a good article on smart/dumb components or containers/components:
[Smart and dumb components in React](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0)